# Why are tests failing due to validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda-matchers

I am writing tests for an application and ran into a problem.

I have the next validation im my model:

```rb
  def correct_date
    errors.add(:occured_at, 'must be in past or present time') if occured_at > 5.minutes.from_now
  end
```

And when I run even the simplest tests on the model, they fail.

```rb
  describe 'associations' do
    it { should belong_to(:category).optional }
  end
```

I get an error:

```
     Failure/Error: errors.add(:occured_at, 'must be in past or present time') if occured_at > 5.minutes.from_now
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, that test will create a new object with a simple `Model.new` call (where `Model` is the model class being tested). In your case, `Model.new` doesn't produce a valid object so you need to tell Rspec what subject to use for those tests:

```
describe 'associations' do
  subject { FactoryBot.create(:whatever_the_factory_is_called) }

  it { should belong_to(:category).optional }
end
```

You should also fix your `correct_date` validation method to handle `occurred_at.nil?`; either validate that it isn't `nil` in `correct_date`:

```
def correct_date
  if(occurred_at.nil?)
    # complain
  elsif(occurred_at > 5.minutes.from_now)
    errors.add(:occured_at, 'must be in past or present time')
  end
end
```

or validate the presence separately and skip the `>` when `occurred_at.nil?`:

```
validates :occurred_at, presence: true

def correct_date
  errors.add(:occured_at, 'must be in past or present time') if occurred_at && occured_at > 5.minutes.from_now
end
```

Making the `occurred_at` column in the database `not null` would also be advisable.

If `occurred_at` is truly optional, then you'd only need to update `correct_date` to account for `occurred_at.nil?`:

```
def correct_date
  errors.add(:occured_at, 'must be in past or present time') if occurred_at && occured_at > 5.minutes.from_now
end
```